# Rails - Testing a model that uses slave replication

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I'm new to RSpec and I'm sure there is an easier way to do what I want:

I want to test one of my models - "UserStatuses.rb".
Each test runs in a transaction.
So I defined:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

I wrote something that runs before each test:

```
describe "UsersStatuses" , type: :model, :focus => true do 
    before(:each) do
        UsersStatuses.delete_all
        user_status = UserStatus.new()
        user_status.save
    end
```

I wrote the test right after the 'before' (inside the describe):

```
    it "Get items"
        res = UserStatuses.func()
        expect(res.length).to eq(1)
    end
...
end
```

The func method in UserStatuses is:

```
def func
    return using(:slave).connection.select_rows("SELECT id FROM user_statuses")
end
```

When I  run the test, it fails.
From what I've seen - the rows returned from func, are the same data that were before I deleted them in the 'before' section.
But when I run the test when use_transactional_fixtures = false, it works (the data in 'before' is saved, and returned in func).

My guess is, that in transaction mode - user_status.save occurs in 'before', it commits to DB, and also to the slave.
Thus, any changes that are made in 'before' - apply to the slave, and func returns what it needs.
But I'm not sure about it.

Is there any way to apply the changes on slave?

Comment: Not sure if it a typo in your post or your code but you have `except` instead of `expect`

Comment: @PaulFrench typo in my code, thanks!
But I still have the problem.

B.T.W, 
the using(:slave) is from octopus gem.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen - RSpec doesn't work well with Shared (in Octopus gem).

I overridden the 'using' method under Octopus::Model::SharedMethods.

So, if at any point in my code I use using(:slave), it will call my 'using'
and the :slave shard will ne be used. All the "changes" will be made in master, and it will be rolled back in the end of the test.

The new function:

```
module Octopus
    module Model
        module SharedMethods
            def using(shard)
                return self
            end
        end
    end
end
```